# C++ POCO lib Linking Error when trying static linking VS9 express

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, linker-errors, poco-libraries

Preview: Linking Error when trying static linking VS9 express

I'm trying to compile a simple application in visual studio 2008 express based on `Poco::Process`. But I'm getting linking errors.

Here is my simple code configured as console application:

```
#include "Poco/Foundation.h"
#include "Poco/Process.h"
#include "Poco/Pipe.h"
#include "Poco/PipeStream.h"
using Poco::Process;
using Poco::ProcessHandle;
using Poco::Pipe;
using Poco::PipeInputStream;
using Poco::PipeOutputStream;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::string cmd = "hostname";
    std::vector<std::string> args;
    args.push_back("--help");

    ProcessHandle ph = Process::launch(cmd, args);
    int rc = ph.wait();

   return 0;
}
```

I added the preprocess flags:

```
Foundation_EXPORTS
POCO_STATIC
PCRE_STATIC
```

And I'm linking with:

```
PocoFoundationmt.lib
```

with Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd) defined, but I'm getting this linking error:

```
1>poco_process.cpp
1>Linking...
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(void)" (??1?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@XZ) already defined in PocoFoundationmt.lib(Process.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(char const *)" (??0?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@PBD@Z) already defined in PocoFoundationmt.lib(Process.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (??0?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAE@ABV01@@Z) already defined in PocoFoundationmt.lib(Bugcheck.obj)
1>msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: class std::locale::facet * __thiscall std::locale::facet::_Decref(void)" (?_Decref@facet@locale@std@@QAEPAV123@XZ) already defined in PocoFoundationmt.lib(Bugcheck.obj)
1>libcpmt.lib(ios.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: static void __cdecl std::ios_base::_Addstd(class std::ios_base *)" (?_Addstd@ios_base@std@@SAXPAV12@@Z) already defined in msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll)
1>libcpmt.lib(ios.obj) : error LNK2005: "private: static void __cdecl std::ios_base::_Ios_base_dtor(class std::ios_base *)" (?_Ios_base_dtor@ios_base@std@@CAXPAV12@@Z) already defined in msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll)
1>libcpmt.lib(locale0.obj) : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl _AtModuleExit(void (__cdecl*)(void))" (?_AtModuleExit@@YAXP6AXXZ@Z) already defined in msvcprtd.lib(locale0_implib.obj)
1>libcpmt.lib(locale0.obj) : error LNK2005: "private: static class std::locale::_Locimp * __cdecl std::locale::_Getgloballocale(void)" (?_Getgloballocale@locale@std@@CAPAV_Locimp@12@XZ) already defined in msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll)
1>libcpmt.lib(locale0.obj) : error LNK2005: __Fac_tidy already defined in msvcprtd.lib(locale0_implib.obj)
1>libcpmt.lib(locale0.obj) : error LNK2005: "private: static void __cdecl std::locale::facet::facet_Register(class std::locale::facet *)" (?facet_Register@facet@locale@std@@CAXPAV123@@Z) already defined in msvcprtd.lib(locale0_implib.obj)
1>libcpmt.lib(locale0.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: char const * __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::c_str(void)const " (?c_str@?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QBEPBDXZ) already defined in msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll)
1>libcpmt.lib(locale0.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: static void __cdecl std::_Locinfo::_Locinfo_dtor(class std::_Locinfo *)" (?_Locinfo_dtor@_Locinfo@std@@SAXPAV12@@Z) already defined in msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll)
1>libcpmt.lib(locale0.obj) : error LNK2005: "private: static class std::locale::_Locimp * __cdecl std::locale::_Init(void)" (?_Init@locale@std@@CAPAV_Locimp@12@XZ) already defined in msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll)
1>libcpmt.lib(locale0.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: static void __cdecl std::_Locinfo::_Locinfo_ctor(class std::_Locinfo *,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?_Locinfo_ctor@_Locinfo@std@@SAXPAV12@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@2@@Z) already defined in msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll)
1>libcpmt.lib(xlock.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::_Lockit::_Lockit(int)" (??0_Lockit@std@@QAE@H@Z) already defined in msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll)
1>libcpmt.lib(xlock.obj) : error LNK2005: "public: __thiscall std::_Lockit::~_Lockit(void)" (??1_Lockit@std@@QAE@XZ) already defined in msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP90D.dll)
1>LIBCMT.lib(invarg.obj) : error LNK2005: __invoke_watson already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR90D.dll)
1>LIBCMT.lib(invarg.obj) : error LNK2005: __invalid_parameter already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR90D.dll)
1>LIBCMT.lib(setlocal.obj) : error LNK2005: __configthreadlocale already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR90D.dll)
1>LIBCMT.lib(lconv.obj) : error LNK2005: _localeconv already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR90D.dll)
1>LIBCMT.lib(tidtable.obj) : error LNK2005: __encode_pointer already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR90D.dll)
1>LIBCMT.lib(tidtable.obj) : error LNK2005: __decode_pointer already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR90D.dll)
1>LIBCMT.lib(crt0dat.obj) : error LNK2005: __amsg_exit already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR90D.dll)
1>LIBCMT.lib(crt0dat.obj) : error LNK2005: __initterm_e already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR90D.dll)
1>LIBCMT.lib(crt0dat.obj) : error LNK2005: _exit already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR90D.dll)
1>LIBCMT.lib(crt0dat.obj) : error LNK2005: __exit already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR90D.dll)
1>LIBCMT.lib(crt0dat.obj) : error LNK2005: __cexit already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR90D.dll)
1>LIBCMT.lib(mlock.obj) : error LNK2005: __unlock already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR90D.dll)
1>LIBCMT.lib(mlock.obj) : error LNK2005: __lock already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR90D.dll)
1>LIBCMT.lib(winxfltr.obj) : error LNK2005: __XcptFilter already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR90D.dll)
1>LIBCMT.lib(crt0init.obj) : error LNK2005: ___xi_a already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(cinitexe.obj)
1>LIBCMT.lib(crt0init.obj) : error LNK2005: ___xi_z already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(cinitexe.obj)
1>LIBCMT.lib(crt0init.obj) : error LNK2005: ___xc_a already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(cinitexe.obj)
1>LIBCMT.lib(crt0init.obj) : error LNK2005: ___xc_z already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(cinitexe.obj)
1>LIBCMT.lib(hooks.obj) : error LNK2005: "void __cdecl terminate(void)" (?terminate@@YAXXZ) already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR90D.dll)
1>LIBCMT.lib(crt0.obj) : error LNK2005: _mainCRTStartup already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(crtexe.obj)
1>LIBCMT.lib(errmode.obj) : error LNK2005: ___set_app_type already defined in MSVCRTD.lib(MSVCR90D.dll)
1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRTD' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'LIBCMT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>D:\cpp\libs\poco-1.4.1p1\poco-1.4.1p1\Foundation\Debug\poco_process.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
1>Build log was saved at "file://d:\cpp\libs\poco-1.4.1p1\poco-1.4.1p1\poco_process\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
1>poco_process - 38 error(s), 2 warning(s)
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

What im doing wrong here ?
Thanks for helping

Comment: Are you sure you want the `Foundation_EXPORTS` preprocessor flag?  Usually the EXPORTS-style flags are used when compiling the DLL.

Answer (score 1):

The library "PocoFoundationmt.lib" which you are using is built with "release static" mode.
From the project you ran looks like you need debug version of library which should be "PocoFoundationmtd.lib".

As you can see from the error log there is a conflict in linking. That is you said compiler the runtime-library is MDd, but you are linking to a release version library. Make sure in your ProjectProperties->Linker you are not linking to anyother libraries and **do link to "*PocoFoundationmtd.lib*"**. Make sure to choose **"Debug" instead of "Release"** at top(near run button) of your project.Also Define **POCO_STATIC**.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you build both the Poco libs and your project against the same C runtime (static/dynamic, debug/release, multithreaded).

Answer (score 1):

I just did this, as Chadwick mentioned, you don't need the Foundation_EXPORTS preprocessor flag.

Also if you set the additional lib directory to poco lib, you don't need to specify the type of dll i.e. MT, Debug etc.

You only need POCO_STATIC as the preprocessor flag.